# Prolog find minimum in list error

Tags: prolog, shortest-path, gnu-prolog

Im trying to make my code work, but somehow I got stuck on a problem, Im very newbie to prolog. This is my code.

```
    dist(valmiera, riga, 107).
%dist(riga, valmiera, 107).
dist(cesis, riga, 70).
dist(valmiera, rujiena,  50).
dist(rujiena, valka, 30).
dist(valmiera, strenci, 200).
dist(strenci, valka, 30).
dist(valmiera, cesis, 40).
dist(liepaja, saldus, 100).
dist(saldus, riga, 200).
dist(liepaja, jelgava, 270).
dist(jelgava, riga, 50).

path(A,B,C,[A,B]):- dist(A,B,C).
path(A,B,D,[A|As]):- dist(A,W,C), path(W,B,E,As), D is C+E.
%, findMin(YList, E), path(A,B,X,E),!.
shortestPath(A,B,X,E):-findall(Y,path(A,B,S,Y),YList), findMin(YList, E), path(A,B,X,E),!.


findMin([],fail).
findMin([H],E):-E=H,!.
findMin([H,V],E):-H<V, E=H,!; V<H, E=V, !; H=:=V, E=H, !.
findMin([H|T],E):-findMin(T,U), H<U, E=H,!;findMin(T,U), U<H, E=U,!;findMin(T,U), U=:=H, E=U,!.
```

but when I call findMin() I get this error

uncaught exception: error(type_error(evaluable,'.'/2),(<)/2)

I'm realy stuck and don't know what to do. Any help will be appreciated.

Applications purpose is get shortest path by calling shortestPath(), paths are in dist (a,b,distance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is because the terms you are trying to compare are lists.

```
[liepaja,saldus,riga]<[liepaja,jelgava,riga] ?
```

An expression:

```
Term1 < Term2
```

succeeds if

```
eval(Term1) < eval(Term2)
```

So, Term1 and Term2 have to be evaluable terms (e.g., (1+1)<(2+2)).

Try to change the shortestPath/4 body:

```
shortestPath(A,B,X,E):-
   findall(couple(W,P),path(A,B,W,P),WP_List),
   findMin(WP_List, couple(Weight,ShortestPath)),...
```

In this way you have a list of couple(Weight,Path) and in findMin you can get the Weight per Path.